# GraphDB WorkBench Similarity Index refresh are disabled when outdated

Tags: graphdb

Using the GraphDB workbench, I have built a few Similarity indexes The first is just the default query and two custom ones. These worked fine for the build. Now they have a status of outdated but the refresh feature is disabled, the UI will not allow a click, instead presenting bubble indicating I cant do it. Only the delete feature is allows. Has anyone determined why this happens and how to fix it? This is the 3rd time it has happened. Yes I can drop a rebuild but I would prefer to find out why its happening. The logs do not appear to have anything related to this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the GraphDB version or move the data folder? Can you point to actions which lead to this behavior?

Comment: The only change is the data itself. loading more owl files for example. Some are public, like Snowmed CT. Though just adding some additional classes and predicates has caused this. The issue occurs when it says Outdated. Biggest problem is if it doesnt update, the UI wont allow re-refreshing or edit of the sparql creating the index. Only Delete is available.

Answer (score 2):

Similarity queries needed for index rebuild are stored in Workbench settings file in GraphDB Home /work/workbench/settings.js. This may happen if you change your GraphDB Home. Please, also check if you have some errors on initialization.

Comment: Thanks, I will check errors. As for installation, its all defaults and unchanged. What does change is adding more data in the form of owl files.